# How To Sort Posts Like The Facebook Comment Stystem

Tags: php, sql, facebook, sorting, comments

I am sure most of you would of used Facebook or know how to use it at some point now I am creating a group feature similar to the one Facebook has implemented on there site but with my own unique features.

The only big issue I have been having and users have requested to do this so I need to make my users happy is sort the posts like Facebook does so the newest comment gets display down the bottom of the posts and the oldest comments get's display right up the top I have tried these but they have no effect 
I am coding this software for the Mybb forum system/software.

[Not sure why stackoverflow didnt put a code block around this so you all know no big deal]
 *$db->query("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX. "groups_comments WHERE post_id='$something' ORDER BY post_id DESC");*

I even replaced desc with asc and tried to sort it different ways.

how would I be able to sort it like Facebook so I can make the feature easier to find comments and to use

Thanks!

Note: There's really no code to see as this is a how to feature as I have not written anything decent but I have tried before asking.

I be great full as I have been searching for days without luck [maybe not searching the right term]

Comment: Add a `created at` Date to each comment and then simple do a `order by` against the created at

Comment: Also, you should order `ASC` if you want the oldest records to come back first.

Comment: sounds like a great idea I try that I haven't heard of that function before but I search it up and see how it goes.
also will you be online tomorrow as it's late here but tomorrow I give this a shoot ;)

Comment: the ASC sort of works @Drumbeg but if there's 100 comments it won't select them all for some reason

Comment: heres a snapshot on what it currently does I want the opposite so 1 down the bottom and 3 up the top so the newest posts bottom to top http://oi60.tinypic.com/37jie.jpg

Comment: I managed to get it to work but when you specify a limit so say limit='4' it won't select the newest 4 posts but if you take the limit out it works fine but I need to limit in to save resources

Answer (score 0):

It seems an error free Query, 
I insist you once again to check your query by triming the white space before the 
" TABLE_PREFIX"... 
ty.

Comment: heres a snapshot on what it currently does I want the opposite so 1 down the bottom and 3 up the top so the latest down the bottoj http://oi60.tinypic.com/37jie.jpg

Comment: I managed to get it to work but when you specify a limit so say limit='4' it won't select the newest 4 posts but if you take the limit out it works fine but I need to limit in to save resources

Comment: i want it to fetch it in decending order bascially but newest results down the bottom first

Comment: $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX. "groups_comments WHERE post_id='$something' ORDER BY time_commented DESC limit='4'"); 

Just Ordr the Comments by the time which they were posted

Comment: thanks for the help so far but the newest comment is still being displayed up the top :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the query you showed us is that the ORDER clause was performed on post_id. All the comments for a given post have the same post_id. Either ORDER BY date or comment_id, and if you want them to be order from oldest to newest, use

```
ORDER BY comment_id (or time_commented)
```

(no need to add "ASC", ASC ordering is the default behavior)

Comment: tried sorting by the comment_id and time didnt work :/